# Are there any better ways to make "ListView" recycling show items?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a requirement: when the last item is selected, jump to first item  if `KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN` is pressed; when the first item is selected, jump to the last items, when `KEYCODE_DPAD_UP` is pressed.

I have one way to implement this:

```
//1. record the last selected item position:
this.getListView().setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        lastItemselected = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }   
});

// 2. add listener to key down
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg){
    if(keyCode == msg.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN){
        if(lastItemselected == data.length - 1 ){
            this.getListView().setSelection(0);
        }
    } else if(keyCode == msg.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP){
        if(lastItemSelected == 0){
            this.getListView().setSelection(data.length - 1);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since I may have many `ListView`, I need to repeat these code many times in my project, so are there any attribute in `ListView` can meet this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

> so are there any attribute in ListView can meet this requirement?

There is no attribute available in ListView to jump between rows on click.

> I need to repeat these code many times in my project

Instead of repeating code many times create a utility class with method which take ListView,position,data-source size length and key event as parameter.